# Facebook Graph API not returning every friend's score

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

It shows the correct number of friends that are using the app, however, when I go to use "/app/scores" to get my friends' scores, it only returns 2 of them.

Here's the code for getting my friends:

```
func getFriends() {
    FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me/friends", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(connect: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var dict = result as NSDictionary
        println("Dict: \(dict)")

    })
}
```

The output is as is:

```
Dict: {
data =     (
            {
        id = 10204187717756755;
        name = "Hardeep Singh";
    },
            {
        id = 629290707196986;
        name = "Ishy Singh";
    },
            {
        id = 1572289319655654;
        name = "Ashlee Carter";
    }
);
```

Then to get my friends' scores, I'm using this code:

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/app/scores", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var resultdict = result as NSDictionary!
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var data: NSArray! = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray!
        var int = data.count as Int
        println("Dict: \(resultdict)")
        //println("Int: \(int)")
        for (var i = 0; i < int; i++) {
            let packet: NSMutableDictionary = data.objectAtIndex(i) as NSMutableDictionary
            let score = packet.objectForKey("score") as Int
            var scoreStr = String(score)
            self.scoreArray.addObject(score)
            let user: NSMutableDictionary = packet.objectForKey("user") as NSMutableDictionary
            let name = user.objectForKey("name") as String
            if (self.name == name) {
                let highScore = score
                userDefaults.setValue(highScore, forKey: "fbHighScore")
            }
            self.nameArray.addObject(name)
            self.globalDict.setValue(scoreStr, forKey: name)
        }
        userDefaults.setValue(self.nameArray, forKey: "nameArray")
        userDefaults.setValue(self.scoreArray, forKey: "scoreArray")
        userDefaults.setValue(self.globalDict, forKey: "dict")
        println("Scores: \(self.globalDict)")
    })
```

Which yields this output:

```
Scores: {
"Ishy Singh" = 20;
"Sunny Singh" = 6;
}
```

So, I don't know how I'm going from have 3 friends who use the app, to only getting my score and 1 others score. I've followed every Facebook documentation and Googled pretty much everything I can think of, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. The users that weren't showing had a privacy of 'Only Me' for the app publish settings, and when I changed the setting to 'Friends', it worked.